# Evento removido antes de iniciar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, eventos, clase

Tengo una clase que extiende EventEmitter y utiliza otro modulo que también extiende EventEmitter y luce asi:

```javascript
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import { events as inputs } from 'gkm';
import _enventHandler from './eventHandler.js'

export default class BarcodeScanner extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super()
    this.options = Object.assign({
      latency: 50,
      minLength: 3,
      endKey: 'Enter',
      validKey: /^\w$/,
      devicePrefix: null
    }, options);
    this._enventHandler = _enventHandler.bind(this, this.options)
    process.nextTick(() => {
      this.initHandler()
    });
  }

  async initHandler() {
    inputs.on('key.pressed', this._enventHandler)
  }

  off() {
    inputs.removeAllListeners('key.pressed',  this._enventHandler)
  }

}
```

**El problema**:

Todo funciona de maravilla, el event handler no importa, es solo una función, pero todo va bien hasta que intento remover el listener:

Este es mi demo (robotjs es un dev module que utilizo para escribir rapido y que se ejecute el `_eventHandler`):

```javascript
import BarcodeScanner from './src/index.js'

import robot from 'robotjs';

let scanner = new BarcodeScanner({
  endKey: 'Intro'
});

scanner.on('code', code => {
  console.log(code)
})

setTimeout(async () => {
  // Type "Hello World".
  robot.typeString("code1lol");

  // Press enter.
  robot.keyTap("enter");

  scanner.off();
  robot.typeString("code1lol");

  // Press enter.
  robot.keyTap("enter");
  
},1000)
```

Si comentas la linea `scanner.off()` funciona sin remover el listener, pero si no, ningun evento es emitido y directamente remueve los listeners antes de ser escuchados.

Dentro de `_evnetHandler` se emite el evento `code` que es propietario del scope this de mi clase `BarcodeScanner` y no tiene nada que ver con el modulo `inputs`. El evento que debe ser removido es el `key.pressed` del namespace `inputs` que se inicializa en `initHandler()` y deberia ser removido con `off`.

Un dato importante es que los eventos que se emiten en mi demo estan dentro de una un setTimeOut() y antes `scanner.off()` estaba en otro con mas tiempo pero aun asi se remueven los eventos y no importa cuando ni donde ejecute `scanner.off()`.

> No incluyo el modulo eventHandler porque realmente pienso que el problema está en la clase. De hecho en el constructor utilizo `process.nextTick()` para asincronizar el initHandler pues me pasaba lo mismo, se ejecutaba el initHandler antes de que los eventos fueran escuchados. Ya intente declarar this.off dentro de nextTick pero no funciona.

De antemano muchas gracias, si se necesita algo mas, estoy atento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en que no estas esperando a que el robotjs escriba ya que es sincrono.El metodo está duncionando como deberia

```
import BarcodeScanner from './src/index.js'

import robot from 'robotjs';

let scanner = new BarcodeScanner({
  endKey: 'Intro'
});

scanner.on('code', code => {
  console.log(code)
  scanner.off();
})

setTimeout(async () => {
  // Type "Hello World".
  robot.typeString("code1lol");

  // Press enter.
  robot.keyTap("enter");
  robot.typeString("code1lol");

  // Press enter.
  robot.keyTap("enter");

},1000)
```

Comment: Oh, no me habia dado cuenta, que tonto, muchas gracias :D